# Changing Azure YAML Pipeline causes authorization to be lost to Resources

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've had this happen to me a number of times where I have a working Azure Pipeline written in YAML. Then I change the Pipeline and then I get the error that `There was a resource authorization issue`. Typically I delete the pipeline, re-create it, and then it works. However, now it is not working and I continuously get the following error:

[image: Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline Authorization error after modification]

So, I click the little button, and it pops up saying, Resources have been Authorized. I attempt to run the pipeline again, and I get the same error.

I am an Account/Collection/Organization Administrator, and created the Library Group originally where it is set to have Access to all Pipelines enabled. I've tried renaming the Pipeline and re-creating it a few times to the same error. short of reverting the pipeline back to it original state what should I do?

--EDIT--

Simply resetting the branch to an earlier version of the pipeline worked. Still no clue on why moving the steps into Stages and Jobs failed though.

--EDIT--

Below will is the YAML I used originally and the updated version. When the updated version gave Resource Authorization issues, I performed a `git log` and took the commit id of the previous commit that worked, and did a `git reset $commitId`. Pushed the reset branch back up to Azure DevOps, then it just magically worked.

Original Azure Pipeline YAML:

```yaml
---
trigger: none

variables:
  - name: ProjectFolder
    value: tf-datafactory
  - group: 'Deploy_Terraform_Library_Group'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: replacetokens@3
    displayName: Replace tokens
    inputs:
      targetFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(ProjectFolder)/variables.tf'
      encoding: 'auto'
      writeBOM: true
      verbosity: 'detailed'
      actionOnMissing: 'warn'
      keepToken: false
      tokenPrefix: '#{{'
      tokenSuffix: '}}#'

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Get the storage account key
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '$(ARM.SubscriptionEndpoint)'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        export ContainerAccessKeyExport=$(az storage account keys list \
          --resource-group $(StorageResourceGroupName) \
          --account-name $(StorageAccountName) \
          --query "[0].value")
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ContainerAccessKey]$ContainerAccessKeyExport"
...
```

I then moved these `steps` into `stages` and `jobs`.

```yaml
---
parameters:
  - name: TerraformAction
    displayName: 'Will Terraform Create or Destroy?'
    type: 'string'
    default: 'create'
    values:
      - 'create'
      - 'destroy'

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: 'Terraform'
    displayName: 'Terraform Stage'
    variables:
      - name: 'TerraformAction'
        value: '${{ parameters.TerraformAction }}'
      - name: ProjectFolder
        value: tf-datafactory
    jobs:
      - job: 'DeployTerraform'
        displayName: 'Terraform Deploy Data Factory'
        condition: eq(variables['TerraformAction'], 'create')
        variables:
          - group: 'Deploy_Terraform_Library_Group'
        steps:
          - task: replacetokens@3
            displayName: Replace tokens
            inputs:
              targetFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(ProjectFolder)/variables.tf'
              encoding: 'auto'
              writeBOM: true
              verbosity: 'detailed'
              actionOnMissing: 'warn'
              keepToken: false
              tokenPrefix: '#{{'
              tokenSuffix: '}}#'

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: Get the storage account key
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(ARM.SubscriptionEndpoint)'
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                export ContainerAccessKeyExport=$(az storage account keys list \
                  --resource-group $(StorageResourceGroupName) \
                  --account-name $(StorageAccountName) \
                  --query "[0].value")
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ContainerAccessKey]$ContainerAccessKeyExport"
...
```

--EDIT--

What I get from this: https://aka.ms/yamlauthz is that you either need to start with Stages and Jobs from the get go, otherwise you have to stick with the original Pipeline that was created. Most people that let Azure DevOps create their initial pipeline won't know to use the Stages and Jobs because the pipeline generator doesn't do that for them and only starts with Steps.

Comment: You can go to Service connections in project setting then select a service connection -> click Security option, check pipeline list in Pipeline permissions section.  Also confused about this:`Simply resetting the branch to an earlier version of the pipeline worked. Still no clue on why moving the steps into Stages and Jobs failed though` Can you give a sample about this?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT, I've updated the post to include code samples without giving out company information.

Comment: This is really strange. Try replacing `$(ARM.SubscriptionEndpoint)` with plain text to see if this issue exists.

Comment: Waiting for the offshore-external resource to actually try implementing this because I don't want to break what we have currently.